# Can't fetch plain text mails content using IMAP

Tags: php, email, imap

I am reading mails from a specific mail id using `IMAP` function.But i am not able to read the mail content for `plain text` mails. It ‘s s working perfect for `HTML Mails`. After running the code all `plain text` mails remains as unread and html mails marked as read and the other things like sender mail id and subject i can read.Only the problem is with reading the content. Here is the code which i have tried

```
    include('imap.php');
    $hostname = '{xxx.org:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
    $username = 'xxx-xxx@xx.org';
    $password = 'xxxxx';
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to : ' . imap_last_error());
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

    if($emails) {
      $output = '';
      rsort($emails);
      foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number); 
            $savedir = dirname(__FILE__).'/uploads/';
                    $attachments = array();
                    if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

                        for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

                            $attachments[$i] = array(
                                'is_attachment' => false,
                                'filename' => '',
                                'name' => '',
                                'attachment' => ''
                            );
                            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                        $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                        $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);
                                if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                                }
                                elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);



                                }

                                 $savepath = $savedir . $attachments[$i]['filename'];
                                file_put_contents($savepath, $attachments[$i]['attachment']);

                            }
                        }
                    }





                $name = $structure->parts[1]->dparameters[0]->value; 
                $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
                 $msg = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2); 

                 $message='';
                if($msg=='')
                {
                    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2.0);


                }else{
                 $message=$msg;

                 }


                 $sub=$overview[0]->subject;
                  $from=$overview[0]->from;
                  $arr = explode('<', $from);
                    $from_mail = $arr[1];
                    if($from_mail!='')
                    {
                        $from=str_replace('>','',$from_mail);
                    }


               $randstr='';
               srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

               $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
               while(strlen($randstr)<5) {
                  $randstr.=substr($chars,(rand()%(strlen($chars))),1);
               }
```

Any one please help me... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is this line:

```
$msg = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2);
```

1.2 is TEXT/HTML email part, which is used for html email body.

1.1 is TEXT/PLAIN - plain text email body - for plain text messages you'll need to use this one.

Comment: Hi, I am using the third parameter values as 1.2, but with this value I am getting empty body content. Can you please share the solution why I am getting empty body content?

Comment: is there html body to be fetched? maybe the email is plaintext only

Comment: yes, body content is plain text and may be html. It will depend on repliers. On searching, 1.2 is used for both type of content. But it is not working practically.