# php - imap_fetchbody message is encoded

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm building a web app where users will be able to see emails sent to their account. I am having some issues regarding the encoding of their messages.

As a test, I just received a registration email from a website. The mail contained HTML.

It should look like this:

```
Thanks for signing up to Virally, we're excited to have you using our product!  
  Start Capturing Leads with Virally!  
  Click here to make your first campaign >>  
  You'll need a digital reward to create a campaign, like an eBook, Whitepaper, Video, free book chapter, Podcast etc. (We can help with this if you don't have anything of your own, just ask)  
  Please hit reply to this email if you'd like some help getting started.   
Thanks,  
 Liam Gooding  liam@virallyapp.com  Virally Co-founder
```

That is how it looks in my inbox; although, on my website it looks like this:

```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```

This is my PHP code:

```
$openmail = imap_open($dns,$email,$password ) or die("Cannot Connect ".imap_last_error());

if ($openmail) {
  echo  "<div class='noti success'>You have ".imap_num_msg($openmail). " messages in your inbox</div>\n\r";
  $tot=imap_num_msg($openmail);
  for($i=$tot;$i>0;$i--) {

    $header = imap_header($openmail,$i);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $header->Subject." (".$header->Date.")";
    $body = imap_fetchbody($openmail, $i,'1');

    echo "<div class='faq-tile'>$body</div>";
  }
  imap_close($openmail);
}
```

The `$body` variable, is the one printing out the body of the mail.

Comment: It looks like some sort of base64. Have you tried `base64_decode`?

Comment: I tried switching imap_fetchbody out with base64, that just removed the entire content. Nothing was printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content you get out of `imap_fetchbody` is base64 in this instance:

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($openmail, $i,'1');

if (preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{76} )+[a-zA-Z0-9]{76}$/', $body)) {
    $body = base64_decode($body);
}

echo "<div class='faq-tile'>$body</div>";
```

You should also read [Can't fetch plain text mails content using IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859600/cant-fetch-plain-text-mails-content-using-imap)

Comment: Okay, that worked for that specific message. I just tried sending an email from my hotmail/outlook account, and it looks like this now: ��^n��z�ޞ׫

Comment: think not actually. Then I'll need a way to differ from the different encoding styles. How is that possible?

Comment: @oliverbj Check my edit - that should help (if the base64 always follows these rules)

Comment: You should be looking at the content transfer encoding header

Comment: If any of you have even looked at the IMAP extension manual for PHP, you'll realise this is not the way to detect the encoding. Using `imap_fetchstructure();` to collect information about the email's parts and use the `encoding` index in the array to get the method of data encoding. `3` equals Base64, `4` means quoted printable strings. Don't try and detect the encoding yourself, you will fail. The problem with h2ooooooo's code is that it'll match literally any normal text data, encoded or not, and scramble it if it isn't actually Base64.

Comment: Looking again, ok, Latin text without spaces (except at the 77th position of each line). It will still fail to match the last line of Base64 data if it isn't equal to 77 bytes, because Base64 is variable-length.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{76} )+[a-zA-Z0-9]{76}$/', $body)
```

didn't work for me, no match for valid data
but

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\r\n+]*={0,2}$/', $body)
```

did work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below to decode the email that you received from email client:

`quoted_printable_decode`

E.g. :

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $mail, "1");
         print(quoted_printable_decode($body)."<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract email message as:

1. Email message that only has a text body and does not have any mime attachments, `imap_fetchbody()` will return the following for each requested part number:

   (empty) - Entire message

   0 - Message header

   1 - Body text
2. Email message that is a multi-part message in MIME format, and contains the message text in plain text and HTML, and has a `attachment.zip` attachment, `imap_fetchbody()` will return something like the following for each requested part number:

   (empty) - Entire message

   0 - Message header

   1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE

   1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN

   1.2 - TEXT/HTML

   2 - attachment.zip
3. Attaching the above email to a new email with the message text in plain text and HTML, `imap_fetchbody()` will use this type of part number system:

   (empty) - Entire message

   0 - Message header

   1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE

   1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN

   1.2 - TEXT/HTML

   2 - MESSAGE/RFC822 (entire attached message)

   2.0 - Attached message header

   2.1 - TEXT/PLAIN

   2.2 - TEXT/HTML

   2.3 - attachment.zip

   ```
   <?php
   //https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open
   if(!$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password, OP_READONLY, 3)) {
     //Show errors
     imap_errors();
     imap_close($inbox);
     die(imap_last_error());
   }

   //Set the date for emails filter
   $date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime("-7 days"));
   $emails = imap_search($inbox, "SINCE \"$date\"", SE_UID);
   //This is sequential number from a loop where you read the mailbox contents
   foreach($emails as $email_number) {       
     //Extract section 1 from email message, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody
     $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1, SE_UID);

     $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 1);
     //Give imap_fetchstructure() previously fetched the email message number
     $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $overview[0]->msgno);
     //Get/set the email subject
     $subject = isset($overview[0]->subject) ? $overview[0]->subject : 'N/A';
     //Get/set your custom date/time format
     $email_date = isset($overview[0]->udate) ? date("d.m.Y", $overview[0]->udate) : 'N/A';

     // Now here is the important part, check the message encoding, read more at 
     // https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure
     //  0  7bit    ENC7BIT
     //  1  8bit    ENC8BIT
     //  2  Binary  ENCBINARY
     //  3  Base64  ENCBASE64
     //  4  Quoted-Printable    ENCQUOTEDPRINTABLE
     //  5  other   ENCOTHER


     if($structure->encoding == 3)
       $message = base64_decode($message);                
     else if($structure->encoding == 4)                
       $message = quoted_printable_decode($message);
   }
   ```