# php imap_fetchbody returns strange characters

Tags: php, imap

Im trying to get the actual text message part of the email with:

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1.2);
```

Problem is I get this:

```
WXuQFOW1/53v6+6Z2Zmdnd1Z9gW7vHYREHZZtzaA4IOAMQKJmBARKfNWkwjRingtklgatEwuPlG4
RI2liSZKAAvwFRKuIlwVUYw8RJ4iKwu7yz7nuTPd/Z37R8/Mzq6zat2qm1RtV1dRS3d/33d+53fO
+Z0zxMxIXwwGExEYzKwIUEAoEv3w+Nljp86FIjFDlyXBgknVw0dXBKWuESCIAHIWISIM6Uvr9xc7
9jIY4Wji9Xc+
```

Do I need to do any kind of encoding here?

Comment: probably base64, e.g. a mime attachment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - imap\_fetchbody message is encoded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838071/php-imap-fetchbody-message-is-encoded)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by placing this code:

```php
$message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2));
```

Comment: Though in this case it’s base64, not quoted-printable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).